# How to define MODELVIEW matrix in Open GL

Tags: opengl, model-view, projection-matrix, frustum

I am doing Camera Calibration, and I have my intrinsic and extrinsic parameters.
I have few virtual cameras, and need to draw frustums for each. I have almost solved that, finding out Projection matrix (m[int]*m[ext]=Projection Matrix), but I still have no idea how to find out Modelview matrix... I need it, for finding current angle frustum, and also drawing camera's local coordinate system.

Comment: Isn't the view matrix supposed to be included in the extrinsic parameters and the projection matrix in the intrinsic parameters?

Comment: Well, talking about projection matrix, we get it with equation m[int]*m[ext]=Projection Matrix, and there is needed some equation or method for Modelview matrix. Standard matrices are not valid for this case, as I am reading calibration data from file...

Comment: Are you sure that the ModelView is not included in your projection matrix? The projection matrix should not depend on extrinsic parameters and the view matrix should not depend on intrinsic parameters.

Comment: OK, then if my equation is wrong, which are right?

Comment: I have solved the problem, and result is here : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2JL1IokHheI
If anyone has same problem, I can advice an algorithm.